# "WebSocket connection to 'wss://***.io/socket.io/?' failed:" with Cloudfront

Tags: websocket, socket.io, amazon-cloudfront

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io('https://whereru.sspzoa.io/', {
        transports: ['websocket'] // without this code, I got 400
    });

    // ...

}, []);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96E0D.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQxko.png)

I am creating a service using sockets. However, when I deploy it using cloudfront, I can't make socket communication with the server.

It works fine locally, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the code. It seems to be a problem with the server cloutfront settings or the format of the request sent by the client.